# Python function with list without any spaces

Tags: python

Define a function convert(input str) to return a list of characters based on the input
string input str. Specifically, each character in input str will be included as a separate element of
the returned list, while any spaces in input str will be ignored

```
def convert(input_str):
    newlist = []
    reallist = [char for char in input_str]
    for k in input_str:
        if k:
            newlist.append(k)
    return newlist

print(convert("Hi You"))
```

this gives output

```
['H', 'i', ' ', 'Y', 'o', 'u']
```

but I do not want the empty space between i and y

Comment: Test if a string is `' '` before appending?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a list comprehension and then filter the resulting list, you can do it in one step using `if` in the list comprehension:

```py
def convert(input_str: str):
    return [c for c in input_str if not c.isspace()]

print(convert("Hi You")) # ['H', 'i', 'Y', 'o', 'u']
```

Instead of using `isspace`, you could use `[c for c in input_str if c != ' ']` instead (although I believe using `isspace` is generally recommended).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add an if statement before you append an item to the list, only `if char != " ":` append `char` to `new_list`

```
def convert(input_str):
    new_list = []
    for char in input_str:
        if char != " ":  # <-----
            new_list.append(char)
    return new_list


print(convert("Hi You"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in method for string that replaces string inside of string with another string. It takes the character that you want to replace and with what you want to replace it with as arguments.

```
def convert(input_str):
    # Replace whitespaces with nothing
    input_str = input_str.replace(" ", "")

    new_list = [char for char in input_str]
    return new_list


print(convert("Hi You"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(input_str):
    newstr = "".join(input_str.split())
    reallist = [char for char in newstr]
    return reallist

print(convert("Hi You"))
```

Maybe this if it is not just one space you are trying to skip